# Tcl pki::pkcs::parse_key error Using Google Auth Service Account Key

Tags: tcl, rsa, x509, private-key, pki

I'm trying to create a small script where I am able to use google's "OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications" with Tcl. After setting up my service account and making a private key in the format of JSON, I copy and pasted the private key that was within that JSON file. (i.e. [screen shot of a part of the private key)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb8Vt.png))

Then I placed the private key within my Tcl script which looks like this:

```
set keydata "PRIVATEKEY"
set key [::pki::pkcs::parse_key $keydata]
```

After doing that, I get the following error:

```
    Expected Integer (0x02), but got 30
    while executing
"::asn::asnGetBigInteger key ret(n)"
    (procedure "::pki::pkcs::parse_key" line 8)
    invoked from within
"::pki::pkcs::parse_key $keydata"
    ("uplevel" body line 45)
    invoked from within
```

I believe I am doing everything correctly. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem was the key that Google gave me was in PEM format rather than the RSA format that "::pki::pkcs::parse_key" requires. Therefore, I just ran the following to convert my PEM key into RSA format and then ran the code shown above and everything works.

```
openssl rsa -in domain.key -out domain-rsa.key
```